# Python mapping values in a list by group

Tags: python, list, mapping

I have the following:

```
mylist = ['A','A','A','B','B','C']

colors = ['r','g','b','w','y']
```

I want all the same elements in mylist to get the same color, from the beginning of the color list, so the result would be like this:

```
result = ['r','r','r','g','g','b']
```

The colors, w and y would be ignored. Can't seem to get the mapping working correctly.

I have tried:

```
result = [[y for y in colors if set(mylist) == x] for x in mylist]
```

Edit: to make it more clear, ['r','g','b','w','y'] doesn't always need to be mapped to ABCDEF... mylist could have been ['cat','cat','cat','dog','dog','bird']

Comment: Does ` ['r','g','b','w','y']` always be mapped to ABCDE or it depends on the `mylist` given ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may first create the mapping as a `dict`, then use it to get the result

```
mylist = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C']
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'w', 'y']

mapping = dict(zip(
    sorted(set(mylist)),
    colors
))
print(mapping)  # {'A': 'r', 'B': 'g', 'C': 'b'}

result = [mapping[l] for l in mylist]
print(result)  # ['r', 'r', 'r', 'g', 'g', 'b']
```

Comment: Thanks! Never used this zip function, learnt something new :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the order of colours:

```
color_map = dict(zip(set(mylist), colors))
result = [color_map[item] for item in mylist]
```

If you care about the order of colours:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

color_map = OrderedDict(zip(OrderedDict((item, True) for item in mylist), colors))
result = [color_map[item] for item in mylist]
```

Comment: dict are keeping order since py3.7 , so is it useful to keep using `OrderedDict` ?

Comment: @azro I must have missed that, thank you for that. However, `set(mylist)` does not keep the order, so I can either use `OrderedDict` for convenince or write my own uniq function (which wold be more performant). `sort` as in your code relies on colours being already sorted, which may or may not hold.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the dictionary instead to keep the mapping:

```
result = []
color_map = {}
idx = 0
for elt in mylist:
    if elt not in color_map.keys():
        color_map[elt] = colors[idx]
        idx += 1
    result.append(color_map[elt])
```

This also avoids iterating over the `colors` list separately.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Counter to count how many times a value appears in your list.

Then use that mapping to fill your result list.

```
from collections import Counter

mylist = ['A','A','A','B','B','C']
colors = ['r','g','b','w','y']
result = []
for idx, (_,v) in enumerate( Counter(mylist).items() ):
    result.extend( colors[idx] * v )
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['r', 'r', 'r', 'g', 'g', 'b']
```

Note: Requires Python > 3.7, otherwise the order of the dict is not guaranteed - this also applies to the other answers here that rely on `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

For me the easiest way would be:

```
mylist = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C']
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'w', 'y']
result = []

for i, item in enumerate(sorted(set(mylist))):  # sets doesn't maintain the order, so its sorted alphabetically
    result.extend(colors[i] * mylist.count(item))

print(result)
```